# How to keep c# process alive (Node server)

Tags: c#, server, process

Hello i'am creating a process in c# that opens a node.js, so far so good but the process seems to end and tipically when i execute the same command from my cmd it stays alive, how can i achieve such thing from c#? Here is the code of the Process

```
     private void buttonStartLLodiAgent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //proc.WaitForExit();
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.FileName = "node.exe";
        psi.Arguments = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/LLodiAgent/main.js";
        using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
        {
            //labelStatusLLodiAgent.Text = "Active";
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
            //process.WaitForExit();
        }

    }
    public void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        outputConsole.Text = outputConsole.Text + "\r\n" + e.Data;
    }
```

I get my Output right, but it seems like the Node service is not up, so i guess it executes but then kills it. 
How to keep the server alive and the c# recieving data?

Thanks in advance, (this is my first post)

Comment: instead of directly executing js from c# call cmd from c# and put execution code on it ?

Comment: YES! how stupid iam, you are right, using cmd worked and its alive

            psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            psi.Arguments = "/C cd "+ AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/LLodiAgent&node main.js";

Comment: cool good luck :)